Error: Number of pixels in mask does not match predictions size in Python/Rasterio workflow
I have implemented a random forest model using scikit-learn and Rasterio in Python to predict pixel values within a shapefile containing multiple polygons. However, I'm encountering an error:ValueError: Number of pixels in mask does not match number of predictions.Here's a simplified version of my script:
shapefile = gpd.read_file(r'C:\SNAP\Random_forest\test\clip.shp')

tif_path_input = r'D:\SNAP_data\S1_imagery\Processing\Final_processing\S1A_20220108_11x11x3x3.tif'
tif_path_output = r'C:\SNAP\Random_forest\test\class\rf_band_only_polygon.tif'

# Function to mask nodata values in a raster
def mask_nodata(arr, nodata):
    return arr != nodata

# Start timing
start_time = time.time()

# Load the TIFF file
with rasterio.open(tif_path_input) as src:
    image = src.read()
    profile = src.profile
    transform = src.transform
    nodata = src.nodata  # Get nodata value from the raster

    # Function to extract pixel values within a polygon
    def extract_pixels(src, polygon):
        out_image, out_transform = mask(src, [polygon], crop=True)
        out_image = out_image.transpose((1, 2, 0))  # Transpose to have dimensions (rows, cols, bands)
        return out_image

    # Initialize an empty array for the predicted results
    predictions = np.zeros(image.shape[1:], dtype=np.uint8)

    # Iterate over each polygon in the shapefile
    for idx, row in shapefile.iterrows():
        polygon = row['geometry']
        
        # Extract pixel values within the polygon
        pixels = extract_pixels(src, polygon)
        
        # # Mask nodata values
        valid_mask = pixels != nodata  # Create a mask for non-nodata values
        pixels = pixels[valid_mask.all(axis=2)]  # Apply mask across all bands
       
        
        # Reshape the predictions back to the original polygon shape
        preds = preds.reshape(n_rows, n_cols)
       
        # Create a mask for the current polygon
        polygon_mask = geometry_mask([polygon], transform=transform, invert=True, out_shape=image.shape[1:])
    
        # Ensure polygon_mask is boolean type
        polygon_mask = polygon_mask.astype(bool)
        print('polygon_mask:', polygon_mask.sum())
    
        # Check if predictions and polygon_mask have the same number of True values
        if polygon_mask.sum() != preds.size:
            raise ValueError("Number of pixels in mask does not match number of predictions.")
    
        # Combine the mask with the existing predictions array
        predictions[polygon_mask] = preds.flatten()

# Write the predictions to a new TIFF file
profile.update(dtype=rasterio.uint8, count=1)
with rasterio.open(tif_path_output, 'w', **profile) as dst:
    dst.write(predictions, 1)

